# Return to while loop, after iteration - when condition is true again?

Tags: javascript, node.js, while-loop, iteration

I am wondering if it's possible to go back to a while loop instead of having to type it all over again?

Simple example:

```
let sum = 0;
let value = 10;

while (sum < value) {
    // do code
    sum++;
};

// sum is changed for some reason outside of loop, after iteration
sum = 3

// iterate through the loop again?
```

Instead of..

```
let sum = 0;  
let value = 10;

while (sum < value) {
    // do code
    sum++;
};

// sum is changed for some reason outside of loop, after iteration
sum = 3;

while (sum < value) {
  // do same code again
  sum++;
};
```

---

I suppose you can create a function with the while-loop but is it possible to handle this some other way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make function for that

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. There's not enough context here to give a good answer.

Comment: Maybe the question isn't that clear. My while loop contains a lot of code, and after the loop, I would like to use it again. But I guess I have to make a function for the loop.

Comment: Yes you have to make a function, a generator, a method or whatever. You need a way to awake that snippet all the times you make a change to the variable, it would be heavy if the processor had to check it at each instruction

Comment: Actually there is a way, I'm going to write an answer for that

Comment: I don't think it is a good one, but maybe it match your  case.. use a setInterval function to keep recall the while loop during some interval..

Comment: Your loop conditions are also different in both cases.

Comment: btw, after a block statement, you need no semicolon.

Comment: ... only in order to mention it, ... JavaScript features `label`s, `break` and [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue). It does not help for the OP's example though, for a `continue` has to be nested inside at least one of both, either a `for` or a `while` loop. But those are language features many of even experienced developers are not aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in a ES6 environment you can use a [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) to watch an object and execute a function when one of its property changes.

```
let obj = {
  value: 20,
  set sum(sum) { 
    while (sum < this.value) {
      // some code
      sum++;
    }
  }
};

obj.sum = 5; // execute the code inside the while 15 times
obj.sum = 10; // execute the code other 10 times
```

You can also give a glance to [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Answer (score 1):

Make loopy function.  Functions help avoid duplicating code.

```js
let sum = 0;  
let value = 10;

function loopy() {
  while (sum < value) {
      // do code
      console.log(sum++)
  };
}

loopy();

// sum is changed for some reason outside of loop, after iteration
sum = 3;

loopy();
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions are one of the fundamental building blocks in JavaScript. A function is a JavaScript procedure—a set of statements that performs a task or calculates a value. To use a function, you must define it somewhere in the scope from which you wish to call it.

```
let sum = 0;  
let value = 10;
valueSum(sum , value);
sum = 3;
valueSum(sum , value);


function valueSum(sum , Value){
while (sum < value) {
    // do code
    sum++;
};

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the values in an array and loop the array and the `while` loop inside of the `for` loop.

```js
var sums = [0, 3],
    sum,
    value = 10,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < sums.length; i++) {
    sum = sums[i];
    console.log('outer', sum);
    while (sum < value) {
        // do code
        sum++;
        console.log('inner', sum);
    }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```